# URL rewrite in Wildfly?

Tags: jsf, mod-rewrite, jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

I built up an app using RichFaces, PrimeFaces, and Java in the back. The outcome (mysite.war) I let run within Wildfly 8.

Now my pages are like this:

1. www.mysite.com/index.jsf
2. www.mysite.com/report.jsf?no=1
3. www.mysite.com/report.jsf?no=2
4. www.mysite.com/report.jsf?no=3
5. www.mysite.com/report.jsf?no=4
6. www.mysite.com/legal.jsf

I would like to change that to more readable URLs. Especially the reports! Taking the example order, I am looking forward to having something like this:

1. www.mysite.com
2. www.mysite.com/report/turkey
3. www.mysite.com/report/germany
4. www.mysite.com/report/england
5. www.mysite.com/report/spain
6. www.mysite.com/legal

I believe I will have to concentrate on the equivalent of mod_rewrite in Wildfly 8? Does anybody know a step-by-step how to for that? Or maybe a short explanation?

Comment: Try [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also want to look at Rewrite, which will be the core of PrettyFaces 4.  It's more dynamic and can intercept URLs if you require login.

http://www.ocpsoft.org/java/migrating-from-prettyfaces-to-rewrite-simplicity-meets-power/

http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/servlet-30/rewrite-a-java-ee-url-rewriting-solution