# Rewrite engine for wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting, wildfly

I'm wondering if It's possible to use Rewrite engine for Wildfly application server without any third-party library. I have tried to use [RewriteValve](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398810-How-to-redirect-traffic-to-HTTPS-), but it did not work with Wildfly 8.x

If it's not possible, Is there any tiny library to use?

Comment: Same issue as this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064922/url-rewrite-in-wildfly

Comment: That issue answered yesterday!! It's similar but not same. And the answer is totally different!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Predicates Attributes and Handlers](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/index.html#predicates-attributes-and-handlers) provided by undertow, you must add the file `undertow-handlers.conf` into `WEB-INF` directory with the rules.

Another alternative is use [prettyfaces](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/).

Comment: Very simple example of undertow-handlers.con content: ```path['/editor'] -> rewrite['/editor.htm']```