# Angular 6 + Java spring boot: Once deployed angular router is not working on page reload(refresh)

Tags: angular, wildfly

Environment:
 - Front end developed in Angular 6.
 - Backend developed in Java Spring boot.
 - Hosted in wildfly app server.

Description:
If we navigate through the route(Angular route) it's working fine. But once page getting reload/refresh, it's throwing 404 error.

This error is throwing from  backend, i think due to the url pattern. To fix that we have to update the deployment descriptor file (i.e. web.xml).

Comment: Does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47926065/1235935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue but on IIS,
i resolved my error by adding **{ useHash: true }** to my RouterModule.

My NgModule annotation in my routing module now looks as following:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [RouterModule],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
})
```

Comment: It work fine but i got some alternate solution as well.
I updated in deployment descriptor file for each url pattern, and redirected to index page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `Wildfly` server is returning `index.html` for all non-static-file GET requests.

Related posts:

[Rewrite engine for wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218940/rewrite-engine-for-wildfly)

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/236258?_sscc=t

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=wildfly+url+rewriting&oq=wildfly+url+rewriting